# How to open all window.open onclick functions in parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my project there are several div elements that contain onclick events like so:

```
<div id='main'>

    <div onclick='window.open("/folder/file.php", "_self")'>
        Content
    </div>

    <div onclick='window.open("/folder/file.php", "_self")'>
        Content
    </div>

    <div onclick='window.open("/folder/file.php", "_self")'>
        Content
    </div>

    <div onclick='window.open("/folder/file.php", "_self")'>
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

The issue i have now is, that this page can be opened in the normal browser window and also within a popup. If this page is opened within the popup i would like all of those onclick links to be opened within the parent window.
Is there a way to accomplish that with javascript or maybe even with jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your own function to open the URL, and have it check whether the window is a popup.

```
function my_open(url) {
    if (window.opener) { // We're in a popup
        window.opener.location = url;
    } else {
        window.location = url;
    }
}
```

Then use `onclick='my_open("/folder/file.php")'`

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple example on codepen :
I remove onlick attribute on the div and the open.window because as your notice you want under the div the load html content ...

Using Jquery

```
$('div#main div').click(function(){
  $( this ).load($(this).data('url'));
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wrejLQ?editors=1111

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. He's not asking how to open all windows at once. He's asking how to make clicking on them open in the parent window instead of in the popup.

Comment: You are missing a `const` before `i`.

Answer (score 0):

it should be '_self'

```html
<div id='main'>

    <div onclick='window.open("/folder/file.php", "_self")'>
        Content
    </div>

    <div onclick='window.open("/folder/file.php", "_self")'>
        Content
    </div>

    <div onclick='window.open("/folder/file.php", "_self")'>
        Content
    </div>

    <div onclick='window.open("/folder/file.php", "_self")'>
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I changed my question to it. Thanks